# use params[:file] as parameter for ActiveJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form with a file upload field, which sends a `params[:file]` when submitted. I want to use this param as a parameter for an job like this:

```
ImporterJob.perform_later(params[:testrun][:file])
```

This however returns an error:

```
ActiveJob::SerializationError in TestrunsController#create
Unsupported argument type: ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile
```

Is it possible to send  a file parameter to a job?

Answer (score 0):

No, with the defaults it's not possible. As the error message imply `ActiveJob` only support some argument types. See full list here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#supported-types-for-arguments

If you really would like to be able pass in a `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` object you *could* write a custom serializer for it. But I don't really see the point of passing in that to a background job since the file is already uploaded...